# Redirecting all users on desktop devices

Tags: javascript, php, redirect

How do you redirect all users on your website, except those browsing on a mobile or tablet? I want to use PHP or JavaScript.

I've tried a few snippets but can't find something that fits my use case - I've only found scripts that redirect mobile users or everyone, no matter what device.

Answer (score 0):

use one of the scripts that perform mobile detection and simply only redirect if a mobile device is not detected.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there isn't a foolproof way to do it in Javascript yet - [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device-in-jquery) sets out two decent approaches, one which grabs the user agent string from the client and one that gets the device width. They each have pros and cons - user agent strings are subject to change, device width leaves you a bit open to confusion on mid-sized devices like tablets; depends on your use case which one works for you.

In terms of how to redirect desktop but not mobile users - both of these solutions are ways of detecting what the user's device is, then storing that information in a variable in Javascript. What you need to do from there is script that redirect behaviour for the group of users you want to move. Google if-statements and "window.location" and you'll find plenty of information out there on how to do that.

Answer (score -1):

use the scripts provided in [here](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/), to detect and include/exclude mobile users: